# Subtracting output of 2 SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm a rookie and am trying to get the difference between two query outputs. Each query creates a list. Query A list > Query B list. Also, query B output is a subset of query A.

Query A:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM users
WHERE rating <> '6';
```

Query B:

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name
FROM users
JOIN mp_positions
ON users.id=mp_positions.user_id
JOIN mps
ON mps.id=mp_positions.mp_id
WHERE mps.status_id = '5';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you may want to update your question with sample data from both quires and the desire output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of the structure of your tables although you'll probably want to try something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM users 
WHERE rating <> '6'
AND users.id
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name 
             FROM users 
             JOIN mp_positions 
             ON users.id=mp_positions.user_id 
             JOIN mps ON mps.id=mp_positions.mp_id 
             WHERE mps.status_id = '5'
);
```

Comment: That worked. I made a small change but it was exactly right. Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: @FranciscoCervera - Mark it as answer then. It will be useful for the future readers

Comment: Instead of `NOT IN` should be used `NOT EXISTS` and `DISTINCT` isn't necessary.